# Snakemake workflow runs locally but not as github action?

Tags: github-actions, snakemake

I have been banging my head against this for a few days now.  I am stumped.  I have tried so many different things, it's hard to keep everything straight.  And running snakemake actually works locally, with pretty much everything I've tried, but this one rule's test always fails as a github action.

The crux of it is, I want to run a tool called `bigwigmerge` to sum the signals of bigwig files.  However, that tool doesn't work when there's only 1 input file, so I decided that for that case, I would use another tool called `bigwigtobedgraph` (because the output of `bigwigmerge` is a bedgraph file).

My initial attempt was this:

```
rule bigwigs_to_summed_bedgraph:
    input:
        expand(
            "results/bigwig/{dataset}.bw",
            dataset=DATASETS,
        ),
    output:
        pipe("results/bigwig/all_summed.bedGraph"),
    params:
        nargs=len(DATASETS),
    log:
        std="results/bigwig/logs/bigwigs_to_summed_bedgraph.stdout",
        err="results/bigwig/logs/bigwigs_to_summed_bedgraph.stderr",
    conda:
        "../envs/bigwig_tools.yml"
    shell:
        # bigwigmerge requires a minimum of 2 files, but the original R script
        # supports 1, so to support 1 file here, we use bigwigtobedgraph
        """
        if [ {params.nargs} -eq 1 ]; then \
            bigwigtobedgraph {input:q} {output:q} 1> {log.std:q} 2> {log.err:q}; \
        else \
            bigwigmerge {input:q} {output:q} 1> {log.std:q} 2> {log.err:q}; \
        fi
        """
```

That works locally when I run:

```
snakemake --directory .tests/test_6_summits --use-conda --cores 2 --printshellcmds all_atac_summits --forceall --show-failed-logs
```

But as a github action:

```
  temporary-summits-delete-after-59-merged:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout Codebase
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Test summits steps only
        uses: snakemake/snakemake-github-action@v1
        with:
          directory: '.tests/test_6_summits'
          snakefile: 'workflow/Snakefile'
          args: >-
            --use-conda -c 2 --show-failed-logs -p --verbose all_atac_summits
```

with the `all_atac_summits` rule:

```
rule all_atac_summits:
    input:
        "results/all_atac_summits.bed",
        "results/all_atac_summits.tsv",
```

It always issues the error:

```
Error in group 8c80e530-b72c-4cd2-ba80-00b10c34aa9e:
    jobs:
        rule sort_summed_bedgraph:
            jobid: 5
            output: results/bigwig/all_sorted.bedGraph
            log: results/bigwig/logs/sort_summed_bedgraph.stderr (check log file(s) for error details)
        rule bigwigs_to_summed_bedgraph:
            jobid: 6
            output: results/bigwig/all_summed.bedGraph (pipe)
            log: results/bigwig/logs/bigwigs_to_summed_bedgraph.stdout, results/bigwig/logs/bigwigs_to_summed_bedgraph.stderr (check log file(s) for error details)
Logfile results/bigwig/logs/sort_summed_bedgraph.stderr: empty file

Removing output files of failed job sort_summed_bedgraph since they might be corrupted:
results/bigwig/all_sorted.bedGraph
Shutting down, this might take some time.
Exiting because a job execution failed. Look above for error message
```

### Things I have tried:

- change `pipe()` to `temp()` -> works locally but same gh action error
- change `if [ {params.nargs} -eq 1 ]; then \` to `if [ "{params.nargs}" == "1" ]; then \` -> works locally but same gh action error
- change `if [ {params.nargs} -eq 1 ]; then \` to `if [[ {params.nargs} -eq 1 ]]; then \` -> works locally but got a different gh action error. I think it was syntax, but the log is gone, so I can't copy/paste it here
- change the shell to:

  ```
  bigwigmerge {input:q} {output:q} 1> {log.std:q} 2> {log.err:q} || \
  bigwigtobedgraph {input:q} {output:q} 1> {log.std:q} 2> {log.err:q}
  ```

  -> works locally but same gh action error
- As a sanity check, change the shell to (I only test the 1 file case RN):

  ```
  bigwigtobedgraph {input:q} {output:q} 1> {log.std:q} 2> {log.err:q}
  ```

  -> works locally AND works as gh action (i.e. I am sane)

I considered using `run` instead of `shell`, but I learned that you can't use conda with `run` because it runs the python code in the snakemake environment for some reason.

I've been struggling to break this up into separate rules, to the point where I'm not convinced it can be done.  I simply don't understand what the problem is and the error in the gh action log is completely uninformative.  If I had such a paucity of debug info locally, I would use `--printshellcmds` so I could copy and paste the command to try it on its own - then I would usually see some shell-level error, like `command not found` or something.  But I can't do that on github and I can't reproduce the error on my machine.  Why would everything work as expected on my machine, but not as a github action?

**UPDATE**: So my boss's workstation is an Ubuntu box, and he can produce the same error that github throws.  My machine is macOS.  So it must have to do with differences in the bash shell that snakemake uses?  He has `GNU bash, version 5.1.16(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`.  I have `GNU bash, version 5.0.17(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin19.4.0)`.

Comment: Obviously, (given my answer below) my sanity check turned out to be a false positive.  I figured out why.  It turned out that I mistook `-v` for the short version of the `--verbose` flag, but it was actually the `--version` flag, which caused the test to succeed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it turns out that there are multiple things going on here...  The factors involved are:

- The `macOS` file system is case insensitive
- snakemake's `--show-failed-logs` only prints 1 of multiple logs
- In a group automatically created by `pipe()`, the log that's printed from the group is not the one with the original error, though I'm sure the subsequent rule would fail as well.

The error was from the rule that created the pipe, but the log that was printed was from the one that consumed the pipe. I know that because my boss looked at the log files when he ran the workflow locally on his ubuntu box and he discovered the "command not found" error for `bedGraphToBigWig`.

The problem in my specific case was that the commands are actually `bedGraphToBigWig` and `bigWigMerge`, but I had `bigwigtobedgraph` and `bigwigmerge`.  Since macOS is case insensitive, it worked without error on my machine.  In the github action, I had no clue what the issue was becasue it doesn't show me the relevant log and I could not reproduce the error locally.

IMHO, `--show-failed-logs` should show **all logs** from **the rule with the error**, not just a single arbitrary log from the rule without the error.

Changing the commands to their actual case made the rule succeed in the github action.

Note, I haven't seen my boss's screen, so I'm taking his word for it that the command not found error was in `results/bigwig/logs/bigwigs_to_summed_bedgraph.stderr` and not to the console.

Comment: Glad you squashed the bug! I fully sympathize with *I have tried so many different things, it's hard to keep everything straight.*